# Is this a strategy pattern or just a callback?

Tags: java, android, design-patterns

I was reading about `SOLID's Open/Closed Principle` today and first example I remembered was `ViewDragHelper` class in *Android* support library.

Here are the details of the class:

```
// allowing a user to drag and reposition views
public class ViewDragHelper {
    private final Callback mCallback;

    public static ViewDragHelper create(..., Callback cb)

    public abstract static class Callback {
        public void onViewPositionChanged(View changedView, int left, int top, int dx, int dy) { }

        public int getViewHorizontalDragRange(View child) {
            return 0;
        }

        public abstract boolean tryCaptureView(View child, int pointerId);

        public int clampViewPositionHorizontal(View child, int left, int dx) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to figure out is it an implementation of `strategy pattern`. Actually it seems like it is. There is the `Context` (`ViewDragHelper` class) and the `Strategy` abstraction (`Callback` class). But there are two points:

- Concrete implementation of the strategy is delegated to an end-user of the library.
- Behavior of the strategy implementation affects the `Context` (you can clamp the view position or forbid drag operation in `tryCaptureView` method), while in `Strategy pattern` description a `Strategy` seems don't have any impact on the `Context` (i.e. only produce or consume some data).

Is this a `Strategy` or some other pattern or just implementation of such a common concepts like `Callback`?

Comment: I'm not sure this is purely one or the other. I'm also not quite clear as to what you think the impact on the context should be? A strategy might define its own variables for a context, so that might be it.

Comment: For me not clear if Context and Strategy can be tightly coupled. In case of `ViewDragHelper` it behavior depends on the Strategy implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this a `Strategy` or some other pattern or just implementation of such a common concepts like `Callback`?

No, it isn't Strategy Pattern in its [classical definition](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/strategy_pattern.htm), it is rather a combination of both, Strategy and [Observer Pattern](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/observer_pattern.htm). `ViewDragHelper`'s behaviour changes with `Callback`'s `getViewHorizontalDragRange()` and `clampViewPositionHorizontal()` implementations (*Strategy Pattern*). And `ViewDragHelper` notifies a `Callback`'s instance about `ViewDragHelper`'s current state through `onViewPositionChanged()` and `tryCaptureView()` implementations (Observer Pattern).

Comment: But `ViewDragHelper` not only notifies. It gets "responses" from `Strategy` and can acts differently. For instance, can don't drag the view to the left if it clamped by `clampViewPositionHorizontal()`

Comment: Now it's clear why it's not a pure Strategy pattern implementation